# Packaging a Jax-Rs web project and hosting it

Tags: web, jax-rs, hosting, packaging

I have developed a java Rest Service in NetBeans.... It is a web application.It needs jax-rs jar files. Now when I want to buy domain and hosting for this project, what kind of packaging should i do?And can I host the resultant file in a shared hosting on Tomcat Server?

Comment: Looks like part of the provided information is irrelevant. i.e. NetBeans doesn't change anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can deploy your application in 3 ways:

1. On JavaEE supporting hosting
2. On hosting with Tomcat — than you'll need to include JAX-RS implementation jars into your `.war` file
3. On any VDS/VPS, but you'll need to set up applcation server/servlet container yourself.

Comment: How do I include jars into my war file? because when i zip my project into war file,it automatically is getting zipped without taking jars,please help.

Comment: 1. It's theme for another question. 2. It strongly depends on build system you use. In case of maven it's packaging type, in case of gradle — plugin.